# What is difference between notations a|b and a/b?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, notation

I am just a beginner. Can somebody tell me what is the exact difference between these notation, if any?
 $a|b$ and a/b

Comment: $a|b$ means that $a$ divides $b$, i.e. $b=ka$ for some integer $k$. On the other hand, $a/b$ is a fraction, i.e. a rational number, such as a half $1/2$ or two thirds $2/3$.

Comment: In particular, "$a\mid b$" is a statement - it is either true or false. $a/b$ is an expression, and it is a number.

Comment: Did you really mean to write a\b and not $a/b$? (Notice how the lines slope in opposite directions.)

Comment: Does $a$\ $b$ mean anything?

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD I've seen it mean $\frac ba$.  Only in a computer science class though.

Comment: Yes. It's a/b. It was a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$a \mid b \iff b=ak \text{ for some } k\in \Bbb Z$$

This is a true/ false kind of statement.  As in, either $a \mid b$ is true, or it's not (in which case we write $a\not\mid b$).

$$a/b = \frac ab$$

This is just a number.  And not even necessarily an integer.

---

Here's a cool example of when we can have $a\mid b$ that wouldn't even make sense as a fraction.  The following statement is true: $$0 \mid 0$$ Can you see why?

Comment: To be fair, when talking about integers, thats the *only* case were the statements $a|b$ and $\frac a b \in \Bbb Z$ are not equivalent :°).

Comment: Whoops, my bad, I meant $a|b$ and  $\frac b a\in \bf Z$, haha.

Answer (score 0):

$a|b$ means $a$ divides $b$.And $a/b$ represents a fraction $\frac ab$.